# Formulas within a reference

Tags: excel

I'm fairly new to excel but have been learning lots. Please go easy on me.

Have 30,000 pieces of data, and constantly filtering this data set. As such, all my formulas constantly need to be updated to the new range (for example, a filter may change my range from `B7000:B9000` from `B1:B30000`). I was able to make it so I can retrieve the row numbers for the first and last visible column.

I was hoping to be able to reference this within my cells to expand my range. What I tried (just as an example),

`=INDEX(Helper!D3:Helper!E3),MATCH...` (rest of the formula is correct)

In the Helper Spreadsheets for `D3` I have
`=Concatenate("'Sheet 1'!U"&D2)`

Where, `D2` is the formula I have used to grab my first visible row. In this case my `D2` displays `7000`

Is this doable or am I totally approaching this wrong? I've seemed to hit a brick wall and I can't figure out how to get this to work. Thanks again.

EDIT:

I am trying to use index and match on a range of cells to populate a fairly large table. Problem is range keeps changing every time I filter data. So I have 30 iterations of this data I need to get through in an already fairly complex algorithm i'm running. I was hoping to save a few steps by having my formulas auto expand depending on the filter, which would save me lots of headache as right now I have to go through and edit each formula by hand to the range the filter sets.

I thought I had it figured out by getting a way to grab the 1st and last visible column, however now I can't enter those into a reference as a formula for example as in the case above.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Both SUBTOTAL and AGGREGATE have functionality that only operates on visible cells.

Comment: `=Concatenate("'Sheet 1'!U"&D2)` is redundant. Either `=Concatenate("'Sheet 1'!U", D2)` or `="'Sheet 1'!U"&D2` would be better.

Comment: Trying to use index and match on a range of cells to populate a fairly large table. Problem is range keeps changing every time I filter data, and I have 30 iterations of this data I need to get through in an already fairly complex process so I was hoping to save a few steps by having my formulas auto expand depending on the filter

Comment: @4ntibody please add information by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773455/formulas-within-a-reference#) your question and not in comments.